# Why use multiple Harry Potters?

Tags: harry-potter, the-deathly-hallows-1

In the scene in *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows: Part 1* where multiple Harrys are created with polyjuice potions, why was the choice to become multiple Harrys?

Wouldn't random muggles be far easier to smuggle than multiple Harrys?

Why was Harry the face of choice?